# Problem with alt+tab switch after removing Cairo-dock

Tags: unity

I recently removed Cairo-dock after using it in a Mac OS-theme, and now I've got two different alt+tab switchers, if that makes any sense. There's the standard Ubuntu switch and on top of that i have an ugly white one.

Anyone knows what it is and how to get rid of it?

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu so I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem and the way i fixed it is

> in CompizConfig Settings Manager -> disable "Viewport Switcher"

I don't know what is relationship between Compiz and Cairo, but
this fixed the problem for me.